# Python cloudpathlib download all files with suffix(csv) from AWS s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pathlib

I am using cloudpathlib to download bulk files from AWS s3. My question is how can I download only csv files using this package?

```
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath

root_dir = CloudPath('s3://dir1/dir2/*.csv')
root_dir.download_to(to_path)
```

In `s3://dir1/dir2/` , there are csv and pdf files. Note that I am not in a position to use boto3 and I generally wouldn’t prefer loops.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
root_dir = CloudPath('s3://dir1/')
for f in root_dir.glob('dir2/*.csv'):
    filename = f.name.replace('/', '_') 
    f.download_to_filename(filename)
```

This assumes that your bucket is named dir1 and that the files are in dir2/ folder.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way not to use the loop?

Comment: `glob` returns a list. I don't think that there is a way to avoid using for or an equivalent structure.